# Converting a String to DateTime with new format

Tags: c#, datetime

How do you convert a string such as 13.11.2017 into a DateTime with that format 13/11/2017

I tried several ways but i didn't get solution  .

```
string Arrival = Request.QueryString["Arrival"];//13.11.2017
DateTime datee = DateTime.ParseExact(Arrival , "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

here is updated code i split the string :

```
            string Arrival = Request.QueryString["Arrival"];//13.11.2017
      string year = Arrival.Split('.')[2];
                   string month = Arrival.Split('.')[1];
                        string day = Arrival.Split('.')[0];
                        string date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                        DateTime datee = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: @GiladGreen yes i replaced it but it gives me an error

Comment: What error does it give? Tested replacing `/` with `.` and for me doesn't give an error.

Comment: A Date or DateTime doesn't need a format when it is created though. Is your goal just to parse it into a date object? When you write it somewhere you would format how it looks. Otherwise it would just be stored as the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.

Comment: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` this error

Comment: Then your string is not exactly how you say it is. Please provide the exact string. Do you maybe have trailing white spaces? (use trim?)

Comment: Could be culture issues. Getting it only when the day is > 12?

Comment: @GiladGreen i updated the question to avoid white spaces

Comment: not sure if it's relevant but you can replace the "." without splitting and reconstructing the string using the replace method in the string object

Comment: If you've split it into day/month/year strings, then why not simply parse them to `int`s and then call `new DateTime(year, month, day)` ?

Comment: this is the error when i split the string `datee' is not a valid format specifier`

Comment: @AdamV example please

Comment: @hashim - [Documentation can be found here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact("13.11.2017", "dd.MM.yyyy", null); should correctly parse it, if a DateTime object is what you need.  But if all you need is the formatted output 13/11/2017, replacing . with / would be sufficient...certainly no need to use Split (and definitely not 3 times!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string Arrival = Request.QueryString["Arrival"]; // 13.11.2017
string dateString = Regex.Replace(Arrival, @"\.", "/"); // 13/11/2017
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString , "dd/MM/yyyy", null); // 11/13/2017 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Observe:

```
// the input string
string inputString = "13.11.2017";

// parse the input string with a specific format to create a DateTime
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// create a string from the DateTime using a different specific format
string outputString = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// output the string
Console.WriteLine(outputString);  // "13/11/2017"
```

Note that a `DateTime` itself does not have any particular format.  A format only comes into play when going to or from a string.

Also note that by using the invariant culture here, we are avoiding any issues that may arise if the current culture was one that used different date separators or a different calendar system.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Russian locale.
Currently using ISO format everywhere to avoid incorrect DateTime understandings (like MM.dd when you mean dd.MM).

```
public static string ToIsoStr(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Your task will be solved with

```
return dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: btw, I was using simple dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") and was still getting "13.11.2017" in the output window with Russian locale set on PC.